# About citing external files in java application

Tags: java, executable-jar

I am writing a java application, in which I am automatically importing external csv files in background to do the computation. But the problem is that I am using "absolute" file path in my java program, the generated jar file will not work in another computer. Is there anyway in java to use a kind of "working directory path" so that I can still run the jar file in another computer as long as I put the csv files I'd like to import in the same folder with the jar file?

Thanks!

Comment: you could pass the directory name as a command line argument.

Comment: @Kishore I am new to java programming. What if I don't want to type in the directory or choose the file in a file-choosing interface, but rather adding a button in the application so that I can simply press the button to import the file automatically?

Comment: how you running jar file?

Comment: @subash Just double click the file :-(

Comment: if you are running in windows , convert your jar to .exe file. then you can automatically recieve the current working directory in args[0] in main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a file using its name like

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }   
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here `text.txt` should be in the same working directory where the `jar` was executed.

You can also read the directory name from the command line, using the command line arguments like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //check if there were any command line arguments
    if (args.length > 0) {
        // args[0] is the first command line argument unlike C where args[0] would give u the executable's name
    } else {
        System.err.println("Usage: java -jar <jar_name> [directory_names..]");
    }
}
```

You can also have a configuration file such as a properties file to read the directory names.

Answer (score 0):

new File(".") give you the relative path

you can write relative path like that :

```
File file = new File(".\\CSVs\\myfile.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

System.getProperty("user.dir") will return you the working directory.

System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\myfile.txt"

More informations here :[system properties, oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)